# PowerBI/DAX - Calculating time difference across different rows

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I'm new to PowerBI/DAX, and am struggling with this. My Data looks like follows:

| ID | Date | Start | End |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 23/4/22 | 08:00 | 08:41 |
| 123 | 23/4/22 | 09:00 | 09:55 |
| 125 | 24/5/22 | 13:14 | 14:55 |
| 125 | 25/5/22 | 05:20 | 06:22 |

Per ID, I need to be able to calcutate the difference between the previous Endtime and the next start time. I know how I would do this very simply in Excel, =IF(A2=A3;B3-C2;""). But I cannot reproduce this in PowerBI.

Thus far I've tried a Self-Join with a shifting index on the "Start" and "End" times, but with no joy. And now I think that perhaps a measure is the correct way to go, but I have no idea where to start with it. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this **measure**:

```
=
VAR FirstDateStart =
    MINX ( Table1, Table1[Date] + Table1[Start] )
VAR LastDateEnd =
    MAXX ( Table1, Table1[Date] + Table1[End] )
RETURN
    FORMAT ( LastDateEnd - FirstDateStart, "hh:mm" )
```

Amend the second parameter passed to the `FORMAT` function as desired.

Comment: Phenomenal. Solved. Thank you very much! I think this goes some way to me understanding the VAR function as well.